# How can I "bend" object coordinates?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, coordinates, vector

[image]

As you can see, the object coordinates don't bend along with the object itself. I know this is intentional, but is there a way to perhaps make them follow the contours of the object, or to manually bend them to approximate the shape, using vector curves maybe? I was unsuccessful with my attempts.

[image]

This is how I'd like the coordinates to bend.

Comment: I'm not even sure if that is possible XD. But can I ask why you need that? Maybe there is another way for you to archieve what you want..

Comment: Well it's complicated xD Essentially, I'd like to be able to use a volumetric material that is a thin, flat layer of cloud, stretched to a dome surface. The cloud has lots of detail made with procedural textures, and I'd like to sort of map that onto a dome. If that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can align the object with the coordinates somehow, and then change it procedurally to the final shape, you can use the *Generated* coordinate space:

[image]

It shouldn't be too hard considering it applies also to shape keys.

Comment: Oh that's nice! Yes, switching to Generated shouldn't be a problem. Shapekeys will work perfectly for me, thanks! Unfortunately though, this won't work with volumetric materials that I need this for. It works well for surface materials, but not for volumetrics, as they do not bend with the mesh coordinates. Do you perhaps know a solution to that? I fear that may be a limitation of volumetrics in blender.

Comment: @Geri all 3 coordinates bend, so I don't see why it wouldn't work for volumetrics. Unfortunately I can't help a lot with that as I lost a small fortune rendering some projects with volumetrics and stay away from them ever since... How about creating an object guide, to which you apply the technique above, and then use that object's coordinate space in another object?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: you are making me curious!!! you lost a small fortune....how did you do that? You rented 10 renderfarms for a year? 

Comment: @Chris renting 10 renderfarms for a year is only a small fortune for you? Can you lend me a few grands without a well precised payback date? ;)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady : I never used Renderfarms so my experience is very very low….

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady That doesn't work unfortunately, the volume stays there and doesn't move with the mesh. Is there maybe a way to achieve what you showed through nodes? I feel like simply manipulating the mesh just won't do the trick with volumetrics.

Comment: @Geri I took a look and volumetric object ignores procedural transformations, that's probably what causes your issues. One idea to investigate is to reverse the shape keys like this: https://i.imgur.com/MI6Xbe7.png then bake the texture from 3 or 6 sides (but with 0..1 data instead of banding which I just use for visibility). 3 sides variant could be used to use the coordinates to read the texel on 3 textures, each showing the offset for different coordinate. The 6 sides variant is where you get 2 values and interpolate between them depending how close you're to one side versus the other...

Comment: Just an idea, no guarantee it would actually work.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for the tip. I'm not entirely sure how to do what you described. How would a baked 2D texture give coordinates to a volumetric material?

Comment: @Geri that's the problem, it wouldn't give it 1 to 1, you would cast the point inside a cube to a point of the nearest surface of the cube, to read how you should offset X,Y,Z coordinates (the offsets stored in RGB values of the texture). Or you could cast the point inside to all 6 sides and interpolate between them, something like this: https://i.imgur.com/SxUexZ7.png (you could combine 6 textures into one)